# Even after setting the "orc.force.positional.evolution" to false hive is still picking up based on position

Tags: pyspark, hive, spark-streaming

I have an external table where I have added few new columns and wanted to ensure that data in orc format file should be written from Spark dataframe to Hive external table based on the column name and not based on position and so have set `"orc.force.positional.evolution"="false"` in TBLPROPERTIES but still data is written based on a position which is incorrect.

Please suggest what I am missing here. I have used below question as a reference:

[Hive external table with ORC format- how to map the column names in the orc file to the hive table columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364304/hive-external-table-with-orc-format-how-to-map-the-column-names-in-the-orc-file)

I have a workaround of using select on spark Dataframe but looking for better options without making any code changes.

Hive version I am using is 3.1

Answer (score 1):

It must be a bug in your case.

In my case I am using a hadoop distribution from Huawei, and I noticed that in their distribution this setting has no effect. **However** it works if you use it in Spark SQL.

The data analysts on your team can use Spark SQL instead of Hive, if they use DBeaver, there's an option to connect to Hive from Spark:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to implement this only for a single table and not at global level, due to this I tried implementing it at tblproperties level. Not sure how can we use it at Spark level ? Also how can we connect Spark from DBeaver ?

Comment: I'm not sure it has effect in tblproperties, you can simply set it to false globally. Regarding dbeaver, you just click on the connect button and choose the icon that I show in my answer.

Comment: I am able to connect to Spark by I wanted to query Iceberg tables using Spark and thats where I am getting error. I dont know how to give Spark --conf or --packages in dbeaver config for Spark

Comment: @Atif what error? You didn't mention any error. I think Iceberg tables are a different story than orc. They should have their own settings. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: So, this is not the original issue but since you brought the topic of Spark connection using dbeaver, I was trying the same and able to query Hive tables and get the count on Iceberg tables(using HMS) but when I try to query Iceberg tables with where clause it throws error. I believe if we can pass certain config like we use to to when opening the spark-sql from command prompt we might be able to fix this.